# How can I make the keyboard trigger resize events in mobile web browser on iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, mobile

I am writing a single-page web app in HTML5/Javascript (basically a telnet terminal). It is using text input a lot, so most of the time the software keyboard will be visible on touch devices.

It seems that on iOS (iPad with latest iOS) showing the software keyboard does *not* resize the page and does not trigger a resize event (in Javascript), causing half of my app's output to be off screen.

Is there any way of changing this default behavior on iOS (maybe with a meta tag, or the like) or is there some other event I can use? I would like to receive a resize or other event whenever the keyboard is shown / hidden and thus the viewport size chages.

Answer (score -1):

How about you try .focus()? If your input gets focused you can trigger resize:

```
$('#input').focus(function() {
  //do resize

});
```

More info on .focus() 
http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem with this approach is that I do not get the new visual viewport size (original height of viewport - keyboard height) in order to resize my page so that it fits on screen without any scrolling. It seems that in Safari the soft keyboard does not change the visual viewport at all, by default, and this is what I am trying to change.

Comment: How about when input gets focused, you shift whole page upwards? This might work for a workaround or I am getting wrong idea what you are trying to do.